# Is there an SNMP feature for Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, snmp

In previous Windows versions, I could install the SNMP feature, which allowed network monitoring software to remotely gather basic system information from Windows. I haven't been able to find anything like that in Windows 10. Am I missing something, or has Microsoft finally ditched SNMP in favour of WMI?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Its in the "Turn Windows Features On or OFF" list in Control Panel> Programs and Features, it uninstalled by default but can be added.

[image]

EDIT: It appears SNMP has been deprecated in Windows 10 1809

[See this list of changes in Server 2012](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/hh831568(v=ws.11)) It was deprecated back in August 2016, so it was just a matter of time before it is for all Windows platforms.

[Microsoft suggests to start using CIM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WmiSdk/common-information-model)

There is a suggested workaround to install SNMP on 1809 in a link in one of my comments, but I have not tested it.

Comment: Ah, of course. Why didn't I look there? I guess I foolishly expected to be able to find it in the main Windows 10 settings. Lesson learned: there are still plenty of settings in Windows 10 that aren't found anywhere except the good old Control Panel.

Comment: Yeah, and Microsoft wants to get rid of Control Panel, idiots.

Comment: Annoyingly, if you click on the Notifications icon, there's a button that says 'All Settings'. In fact, what you get is nowhere close to all of the available settings. It's just the ones they've bothered to convert to the goofy new UI. In fact, if you drill down into those far enough, you usually end up at the familiar old settings dialogs from Windows 7. But nowhere in there is a link to the Control Panel. For that, you have to right click the Start button.

Comment: You can add the shortcut to the desktop, Settings>Themes>Desktop Icon Settings

Comment: Yeah, but it's still well hidden by default.

Comment: Hiding is the next step on the way to eliminating. Windows machines are becoming nothing more than a kitchen appliance, sad indeed.

Comment: The thing that amazes me is that Microsoft no longer seems to care about business/education customers. They'll keep using Windows 7 until 2020, and then switch to Linux probably.

Comment: Same here, Windows is forcing me to Linux, BSD or Mac.

Comment: Interestingly, the kind of stuff that they're doing with Windows 10, the privacy issues, the focus on a simplified, touch interface, and so on, I find unacceptable in a desktop O/S, but it doesn't really bother me on my phone.

Comment: Latest Windows 10 (1809 - OS Build 17763.253) does not have SNMP listed. Seems like it has been removed from Windows 10.

Comment: Yup, it has but you can still install it, scroll to bottom and look for blue checkmark on answer.....https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/440441a0-5fd2-41b2-a938-91ede7e85ea4/windows-10-1809-installs-but-no-snmp?forum=win10itprosetup

Comment: it works indeed, but you just need to use the last command from his post : add-windowscapability -online -name "SNMP.Client~~~~0.0.1.0" (as admin)

Comment: I have Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.253] and its there in mine. Installed by default. I'm not seeing the point of all the Microsoft bashing (and Linux praising) here and wonder how you guys will manage an enterprise system with Linux and no AD.

Answer (score 4):

The Microsoft TechNet wiki page titled ["How to Install SNMP Remotely"](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4032.how-to-install-snmp-remotely.aspx) authored by [Andrew Karmadanov](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/profile/andrew%20karmadanov/) has incredible amount of detail on how to install the SNMP service.  This answer is a copy-and-paste of the relevant parts of Andrew's wiki page.  Note that the Windows SNMP agent does not support v3, see this for more info: https://serverfault.com/questions/818237/is-snmp-v3-supported-in-windows-server-2016/818472.

## 1. Install

#### 1.1 Install - Graphical

Start->Control Panel->Programs and Features->Turn Windows Features on or off->Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP)->WMI SNMP Provider->Enable checkbox.

#### 1.2 Install - Command-line

For Windows 10,

Run cmd.exe as administrator. From the elevated command prompt, type:

```
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:"SNMP" /featurename:"WMISnmpProvider"
```

## 2 Configuration - User Interface

In Windows 10, the user interface is "hidden" in the services.msc *Properties* of the *SNMP Service* itself.  For more info, see this Paessler The Network Monitoring Company Knowledge Base [page](https://kb.paessler.com/en/topic/663-how-do-i-install-the-snmp-service-on-windows-systems) for details.

## 3 Configuration - Windows Registry

All the SNMP settings are stored in registry, which makes this task a bit easier. The settings we need to configure are shown below.

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SNMP\Parameters\EnableAuthenticationTraps
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SNMP\Parameters\NameResolutionRetries
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SNMP\Parameters\PermittedManagers
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SNMP\Parameters\TrapConfiguration
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SNMP\Parameters\ValidCommunities
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SNMP\Parameters\RFC1156Agent\sysContact
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SNMP\Parameters\RFC1156Agent\sysLocation
```

EnableAuthenticationTraps, NameResolutionRetries, sysContact, and sysLocation are just registry values. We can leave them untouched. ValidCommunities, PermittedManagers, and TrapConfiguration are way more important. They define what systems can communicate to the host via SNMP

#### 3.1 ValidCommunities

The ValidCommunities key contains the list of SNMP communities and permissions. It looks like

```
"<Community Name>"=dword:<Access Rights>
```

The access rights have the following values:

```
NONE – 0x0001
NOTIFY – 0x0002
READ ONLY – 0x0004
READ/WRITE – 0x0008
READ/CREATE – 0x0010
```

For example:

```
"public"=dword:00000004
"private"=dword:00000008
```

#### 3.2 PermittedManagers

The PermittedManagers key contains the list of hosts, which can query or update a host via SNMP. It is a numbered list of names or IP addresses. For example:

```
"1"="10.10.10.1"
"2"="MonitoringServer.doamin.com"
```

#### 3.3 TrapConfiguration

The TrapConfiguration key is a list of subkeys, one per community names. In turn every subkey contains a list of hosts, to which the traps will be sent. For example:

```
TrapConfiguration\public
"1"="10.10.10.1"
"2"="MonitoringServer.doamin.com"
```

Note: Community names are case-sensitive

Answer (score 1):

If you have Windows 10 1809 OS build 17763.xxx, you can find SMTP in:
 Settings(windows settings) --> Apps --> Apps & Features --> Manage optional feature --> Add Feature and than find it in the list.

[image: SNMP feature in Win10 1809]

You must have an internet connection to install this feature.

Comment: ...and you also need "WMI SNMP Services" to finally get all the configuration tabs for the SNMP service